# How to display data in php?

Tags: php

I have a table like this in my phpMyadmin:

| id | grp | user1 | user2 | user3 | user4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | b | c | d |
| 2 | 2 | e | f | g | h |

etc.

How do I display grp 2, when e, f, g & h are displayed.

Currently, I tried the code below however, it will display all the values in the column row. I just need the one value of grp that corresponds with the user1,user2,user3 and user4 columns.

```html
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","12345","login");
if ($conn-> connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * from groups";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);


    
    
while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {

    echo $row["grp"];
    
}
    

$conn-> close();
```

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause in your statement, matching one of the user columns (or all of them, if one user can be in multiple groups).

Comment: ok thank you for your help